# How to scroll back to top on change screen react js and lenis smooth scroll

Tags: reactjs, web

I am using lenis to have a smooth scroll and i have a ScrollToTop.js which i use in my App.js. it works fine when the page is not being scrolled but when i click a button that will take me to another page while the "smooth scroll" is happening the scrollToTop wont work, does anyone know how to solve this?

ScrollToTop.js

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import { colors } from "./constants";

export default function ScrollToTop() {
   const { pathname } = useLocation();
   const body = document.querySelector("body");

   useEffect(() => {
     window.scrollTo(0, 0);
     // gsap.to(body, { duration: 0, backgroundColor: colors.white });
   }, [pathname]);

  return null;
}
```

I have tried using useLayoutEffect in each page but not working

Comment: Most likely `lenis` also uses the browser API to scroll so they may be interfering with each other. Potential solution is disabling `lenis` scroll before switching routes.

Answer (score 0):

you can disabling lenis scroll before switching routes.